# Angular directive for range validation

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am trying to make a directive for an `input` to limit the value between `1-99`. On the same input I also have another directive that converts the value to a percentage and am not sure if that is what is getting in the way.

The directive is simple (taken basically from the Angular website):

```
(function() {
  'use strict';

  angular
    .module('app.model')
    .directive('inputRange', inputRange);

  function inputRange() {
    return {
      require: 'ngModel',
      restrict: 'A',
      link: function(scope, elm, attrs, ctrl) {
        var INTEGER_REGEXP = /^-?\d+$/;
        ctrl.$validators.inputRange = function(modelValue, viewValue) {
          if (ctrl.$isEmpty(modelValue)) {
            // consider empty models to be valid
            return true;
          }

          if (INTEGER_REGEXP.test(viewValue)) {
            // it is valid
            return true;
          }

          // it is invalid
          return false;
        };
      }
    }
  }
});
```

And the section of html with the input field (which is paired with a slider):

```
  <form name="form">
    <div sc-slider
        ng-model="vm.baseline"
        min="0.01"
        max="0.99"
        initial="{{vm.baseline}}"
        step="0.01"
        uib-tooltip="The initial estimate of the KIQ's likelihood - prior to any indicator observations."

        tooltip-popup-delay="200"
        tooltip-popup-close-delay="200"
        tooltip-placement="bottom"></div>
    <input to-percent
        input-range
        name="baseline"
        style="text-align:center;"
        type="text"
        min="1"
        max="99"
        class="form-control"
        ng-model="vm.baseline"></input>
    <span ng-show="form.baseline.$error.inputRange">The value is not a valid integer!</span>
    <span ng-show="form.baseline.$error.min || form.baseline.$error.max">
      The value must be in range 1 to 99!</span>
  </form>
```

I have read on SO about priority for directives that share an input but I don't think that is necessarily an issue here. But when I enter a value greater than `99` I'd expect one of the spans below to show up, but nothing is appearing. And my other directive works fine all of the time. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Not sure if this is the problem, but it seems like you're not invoking the directive's IIFE.

Answer (score 0):

Make your life easier and use `ng-max` and `ng-min` attributes on the input element.

Comment: Is this supposed to replace the directive all together or go in conjunction with it?

Comment: Using ng-min and ng-max, you'd hand over the range check using the attributes and you don't have to build a custom directive for that.

Comment: Okay, I have looked at a few examples, but in this case, just simply adding `ng-min / ng-max` doesn't prevent a user from inputting numbers larger than the max?